# Unable to insert images so you can see what I'm talking about

Tags: discussion

The message "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed".

I have a AMD Win7 64-bit system I'm trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 on but it gets stuck. I've managed to install Ubuntu but it freezes. I'm trying to figure out how to add photos to the questions to help others answer them. How do I add images beside type in the entire url?

Comment: You can not add picture until you have sufficient reputation. Add them to a photo pastebin off site and post a link back. From your question, it sounds as if your problem is phrasing the question and not with pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Check the circle]

**EDIT:**

You can follow these steps, after you reach a reputation of 10.

This is the button, that you can use to upload the image on any question or answer. It will prompt an uploading dialogue where you can drag and drop the image you want, or you can access your own directory to upload a file.

Other than that, you can also use some websites where you can upload your screenshots and a give link to it inside your question or answer.

Examples:

[Print Screen dot com](http://prntscr.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: That will not work until he has more reputation.

Comment: I edited my answer. BTW thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: @DavidH please mark it as a correct answer, if it helped :)

Comment: Where do I mark it as correct?

Comment: How long does it take to have 10 repo?

Comment: It takes effort, not time to get 10 reputation, so ask your question, make the screen shots, post them somewhere on the web (imgur.com. picasaweb.google.com) and then provide the link (max 2) in your question

Comment: What @Fabby didn't add is that someone else will come in and edit them inline for you ;)

Comment: @Seth That's what I was going to do...  Now it's up to you!  >:)  (I'm off to sleep)

Comment: @DavidH there's a sign below the number of votes for an answer. You can mark any answer correct that you find helpful. It helps others to find the correct solution for the same problem, a lot more easier.

Comment: and it also helps you gain reputation